# AVPlayer does not display any video on physical device but displays on the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

At first I want to mention that I'm using [MobilePlayer](https://github.com/mobileplayer/mobileplayer-ios) library but it's just a skin above `AVPlayer`.

When I tap to play video it only plays sound and I do not see any video. I've checked `view` bounds but the problem is not there. At the beginning of the video it indicates loading progress but later I hear only the sound without any video.

My code looks like:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let config = MobilePlayerConfig(fileURL: bundle.url(
                forResource: "Skin",
                withExtension: "json")!)

let videoURL = NSURL(string: channelURL!)
self.playerVC = MobilePlayerViewController(contentURL: videoURL! as URL, config: config)

self.playerVC.activityItems = [videoURL! as URL]

self.present(self.playerVC, animated: true)
```

I also want to mention that I see the video when I run on the simulator but on the real device there is no video at all. What can be a problem?

If you need any part of the code just ask me please

Comment: Are you sure that your video's codec is supported on device?

Comment: @DanKarbayev it's H.264 format. So yes, it should support